# Zend PDF: How do I print bold text or text in another color etc?

Tags: html, styles, zend-pdf

I have a long string, like:

*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore **magna** aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.*

Some of the words should be bold and some text should have another color and so on. Is it somehow possible to give the drawText function a string that already contains the correct syntax so the PDF will have the bold text and so on? Something like this:

```
$text = "my <b>text</b>...";
$page->drawText($text, 100, ($page->getHeight() - 100));
```

Its not working with HTML, but something simliar?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question is no, Zend Framework does not provide the formatting functions that you are looking for.

`Zend_Pdf` provides the primitive functions for drawing text, lines, circles, etc onto the page, but that's about it. If you want to bold some text in the middle of a line, you have to draw the first bit of text, change the font style to bold, draw the bit of text you want bolded, switch back to the original font style and then draw the remainder of the line. And you have to look after line wrapping, page breaks, etc, yourself too.

I wrote a blog post some time ago that talks about these challenges in more depth and have posted a wrapper class on github that makes `Zend_Pdf` a little easier to use. The post is here: http://yetanotherprogrammingblog.com/content/zend_pdf-wrapper-and-sample-code and the wrapper class is here: https://github.com/jamesggordon/Wrap_Pdf. Unfortunately this version of the class doesn't do precisely what you want, but it shouldn't be too hard to modify the `writeText()` method to implement the font changing system that you're after.

Answer (score 1):

I too am looking for something similar. We have some legacy code that renders a PDF using Zend PDF.. it's very complicated.

I have in the past used something called DomPDF - this is probably what you need as it just turns HTML into PDF for you - very easy to use!

http://dompdf.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, check out zend.pdf.drawing;
http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.pdf.drawing.html

You'd need to break your PHP strings up, then change the Zend PDF drawing styles between each PHP string.

```
$style->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES_BOLD), 12);
$page->setStyle($style);
$page->drawText(....);
$style->setFont(\Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithName(\Zend_Pdf_Font::FONT_TIMES), 10);
$page->setStyle($style);
$page->drawText(....);
```